# Install Wordpress ONLY as the landing page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I currently have a full site developed using custom html, php & css, however find updating the home page time consuming (startup- multiple iterations). I've seen people installing wordpress on subdomains (test.example.com) and even subpages (example.com/test) but amn yet to see someone install it as the landing page itself. Is this possible without a redirect? If so, how?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem and won't be easy to sort out. Focus on making it easier to update your home page contents instead

Comment: Just install it at the root of the folder, WP+Apache htaccess will handle it.

Comment: What is “the landing page itself”? To me, a “landing page” is just a URL, and you’ve shown two URL examples that WordPress works with. What else are you looking for? Do you just want WordPress to control a single page? If so, yes, just publish one page.